# Want to create a table using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table, working on a pugin project

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am adding only three columns to the table but an extra column is also being displayed, I want exactly three columns. While resizing the window the column size is not increasing , what should i do. I am using GridLayout, should I use other layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some code to show? It could help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TableColumnLayout`. See http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/05/single-column-tableviewer-and.html and http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/11/one-of-less-prominent-novelties-in.html.